# Can BMC Control-M pick up a file and write them to IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, control-m

Are there any BMC control-m extensions to send messages to IBM MQ? I have seen something called Mainview but it's primarily for listening and monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Mainview is a mainframe product. For Control-M (distributed) you can use the "Control-M for Web Services, Java and Messaging" extension to send stuff to MQ.